VB.Net How to get font to properly scale with form?
I made a program for my wife's work. My computer is at 1920x1080 and my wife's laptop is 1336x768. However the text is not sizing properly between the two.
I have labels on the left hand side of text boxes. Ex: Date: [Textbox]
The label font is not relative to the size of the program. The label text is becoming too large and overlapping the text boxes. I have attempted to change the forms scaling method(dpi, font, none). I have also changed the fonts to pixel scale. None of which have helped.
Other than moving visual studio to my wife's laptop and fixing it there, what can I do?


Specify the .NET version you're targeting and the DpiAwareness mode, if any -- Positioning labels on the sides of other Controls, you always have some issue (e.g., assume you have to translate that text in other languages). The length of the text, or the Font itself, may change (a Font can be replaced / remapped if it's not available in a machine, the text can be scaled because of local screen configuration). Place it above the related Control. Or use an auto-sizing TableLayoutPanel to handle the layout -- Use nested Containers to position groups of Controls functionally related to each other

Maybe you can position the textbox at runtime where the last letter of the label ends. It's best not to do this based on the string length, since the letters can have different widths. Instead, you can use TextRenderer.MeasureText(yourString, yourFont).
